# Deserialize JSON with special characters in property name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json property like "A\/B" and I want to deserialize it in c# property AB

I have tried both System.Text.Json and

```
[JsonPropertyName(@"A\/B")]
public bool AB { get; set; }
```

Or

```
[JsonProperty(@"A\/B")]
public bool AB { get; set; }
```

Or

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = (@"A\/B")]
public bool AB { get; set; }
```

or

```
[JsonPropertyName("A\\/B")]
public bool? AB { get; set; }
```

but is not deserialized correctly is always false and in the json file is true like "A/B": true,.

Json example :

```
{
    "List": [
        {
            "Name": "name",
            "A\/B": true,
        },
        {
            "Name": "name1",
            "A\/B": false,
        }
    ]
        
}
```

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show a sample of the json? Note that the backslash is also used as an escape character in json.

Comment: I've added a json example snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the JSON looks like

```
{
    "A\/B": true
}
```

**Then the name of the property is actually *just* `A/B`.**

The backslash character also acts as an escape character in JSON syntax, so the backslash isn't actually part of the property name. Even though the forward slash doesn't need any escaping in this case, it is still acceptable to escape it nonetheless. See [RFC 8259 section 7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#section-7).

So, in your C# code, you also don't need any backslashes:

```
[JsonProperty("A/B")]
```

or

```
[JsonPropertyName("A/B")]
```

depending on whether you are using Json.NET or System.Text.Json.

Comment: I'm using System.Text.Json/System.Text.Json.Serialization and now it's working thanks a lot